# initializing python object with nothing but keyword args

Tags: python, object, constructor, instantiation

I am wondering how to initialize an object in python with only named args, and nothing else, if this is possible.

[image]

If the order of self.name = name and self.age = age are swapped, the error is with initializing age. I have these given as keyword args to the object, so why is that not enough? I saw a class in dive into python instantiated with explicitly named keyword arguments and their default (filename=None), so I assumed **kwargs would work too. Thank you

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your question, but FYI would be better to paste text code rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're missing is that kwargs need to be explicitly retrieved by name.  Here's a modified version of your code, to illustrate.  Note the initialization of `name` and `age`.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.age = kwargs.get('age')
        # you'll probably want to check that all required
        # members were initialized.

bob = Person(name='bob', age=45)

print bob
print bob.age
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Person object at 0x1074e0bd0>
45
```

Comment: and using *args can be done with self.first_arg = args[0]  :)

ty Mr. Rothman

Answer (score 3):

`kwargs` is a dictionary. So you should rather do this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs["name"]
        self.age = kwargs["age"]
```